# Overriding Web.config keys from env

Tags: asp.net, web-config

We are using ASP.NET core and paubox library to send secure emails. For this, the library want to add following key in *Web.config* file => appSettings.

```
<add key="APIKey" value="11111"/>
<add key="APIUser" value="user@test"/>
```

The problem is we don't want to commit the key/user into GIT.

All other configuration variables are being read from *.env* file using:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()
```

Is it possible to overwrite Web.config appSettings keys from .env?

It should be a common requirement but couldn't find anything anywhere.

Comment: The old pattern was to use config file transformations

Comment: If you don't want to use web.config to store your API key and user, then don't. There's nothing stopping you from reading those values from some other file, or environment variables, or some configuration DB or service.

Comment: The problem is, the library auto loads it from web.config and the variables in the class are private

Comment: The only feasible way is to patch the library to prevent it from loading values from config file. ASP.NET does not provide you any mechanism to simply override that.